# Cocos2d-x app fail to compile for Android

Tags: android, c++, visual-studio, cygwin, cocos2d-x

*Used software:

Visual Studio 2012 Express

cocos2d-x 2.0-x-2.0.4

cygwin 1.7.5.

Eclipse 3.8

Android SDK last

Android NDK r8c*

I am new in development for Android, so don't understand what is wrong. 
Trying to build cocs2d-x standart testcpp project.
First trouble was when when i runned `create-android-project.bat` - it didn't shows target versions of Android (target - v.2.3.3.), but all paths are correct.

At last it build project folder. But next step - building pack in cygwin - fails in case of hundreds of "file or folder not exists" errors of headers, didn't uses a lot of STL headers and ask for `<string.h>` but not just `<string>`.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: No more Cygwin based builds. And probably I should pass some parameters to compiler.

Comment: It's my old crappy question about fighting with building pipeline. This will not help anyone, so it should begone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must rename APPNAME variable in build_native.sh same to your eclipse project name

Answer (score 0):

set NDK path in build_native.sh file in android project folder, then excute `build_native.sh` by using cygwin

Comment: NDK_ROOT was defined. errors appears when cygwin's make.exe enters to project folder and show line `Compile++ thumb  : hellocpp_shared <= main.cpp`.  Father text is try to include files, but a lot of just not exists and standart headers ignored by this utility. There was a answer to add `APP_STL:=stlport_static` inside "application.mk" but doesn't work too.

Comment: error code? message appears in cygwin. First of all error appears in CCSet.h `fatal error: set: No such file or directory`. Inside of that header it defined as  `#include <set>`.

Answer (score 0):

try to update android-NDK, I have same error using NDK-r8d, and try to execute build-native script too.